# Prove $f(0_n)=0_m$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map, prove that $f(\boldsymbol{0}_n)=\boldsymbol{0}_m$

Can someone explain how I would prove this? I understand that to be a linear map it must satisfy...

1) $F(x+y)= F(x)+F(t)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

2) $f(cx)=cF(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all scalar $c \in \mathbb{R}$

But I understand how to apply this information into proving $f(\boldsymbol{0}_n)=\boldsymbol{0}_m$.

Comment: Btw you can use LateX in the title too :P

Answer (score 2):

Set $c=0$ in your second condition.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0) +f(0) \\ \text{... subtract $f(0)$ from both sides ...} \\ f(0) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0) + f(0) = 2 f(0)$$
adding $-f(0)$ to both sides finishes proof.